# как заставить JPanel накладыватсья на JPanel

Tags: java, swing

Суть в том, что я добавил фото как Background, и сверху хочу еще добавить элементов (линии, другие панели, текс - это не важно), но при добавлении, новый объект заменят предыдущий, а не накладывается на него, подскажите как это можно исправить

Comment: попробуйте OverlayLayout

Comment: Покажите кусок примера кода

Comment: @ezhov_da куском наверное не обойдусь, там несколько классов, по факту мне бы хватило логики, или самого простого примера, где две панели, грубо говоря красный квадрат, и поверх желтый который в два раза меньше, и все они видны, но если так будет удобней, вот ссылка на проект https://github.com/Zherikhov/TicTacToe

Comment: Посмотрел Ваш проект - много неверной логики, например из этого кода:         mainPanelBottom.add(game, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainPanelBottom.add(setting, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainPanelTop.add(gameBackground, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanelTop.add(settingField, BorderLayout.CENTER); установится последний компонент

Comment: Объясните на Вашем примере чего вы пытаетесь добиться?

Comment: @ezhov_da я пишу по сути банальные крестики нолики Сначала открывается окно настроек, там можно будет выбрать с кем играть (человек/компьютер), после нажатии на кнопку играть, появляется поле. Сейчас у меня там просто фото как задний фон, сверху я хочу прорисовать поле линиями, и если я добавляю любые элементы на соответствующие поле, то они заменяют задний фон, а не прорисовываются сверху

Comment: @ezhov_da соответственно в любой момент я могу переключиться назад (на поле настроек) поменять что-то, и начать заного

Answer (score 0):

В общем, не сразу получилось, но для меня очень полезна оказалась данная статья - http://www.skipy.ru/technics/gui_int.html